# DevExpress: SimpleButton with Image: transparency?

Tags: devexpress

I tried to create a DevExpress SimpleButton button that uses picture instead of text:
1.  I have created the picture in MS Paint. The picture was a red square. I saved this as a BMP file
2.  I imported the BMP into my Win Forms application as a resource.
3.  I have created a SimpleButton button on a form
4.  I have assigned the imported image into Image property of the button.
The button looks NOT as the ‘red square’ – the used Skin ‘overrides’ the image, actually.
What should I do? I want the button to display EXACTLY that my image.

Answer (score 1):

```
simpleButton1.ButtonStyle = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.BorderStyles.Flat;
```